# Controlling the height of a mat-chip

Tags: css, angular, angular-material

How is it possible to change the height of an angular material chip ?

```
<mat-chip-list>
  <mat-chip>Example</mat-chip>
</mat-chip-list>
```

The default implementation sets the min-height to 32 pixels
[image]

Comment: `body .mat-standard-chip { min-height: 40px !important}` put it in main css file

Comment: @SonNguyen your comment will not allow users to selectively have full height mat-chips in some places, and other height mat-chip's in other places.

Comment: oh didn't think you want to set only one chip. how about applying a style around your chip container element and refer to it like `.short-chip .mat-standard-chip`? need to inspect the actual markup Mat generates to find the right selector

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The mat-chip will have `min-height: 32px` and `height: 1px` as default.
With longer text/paragraph under `mat-chip` you will receive the default `min-height: 32px` only.

So you can control the height by setting it to `auto` as follows,
In your CSS,

```
.mat-standard-chip {    
   height: auto !important;
 }
```

If you want to use for the specific chip with class name/ ID, you make use of same height property with some pixels.
Example:

```
.small-chip {
   height: 20px !important;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use below properties:

```
.mat-standard-chip {
   min-height: 22px !important;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply add a custom class to your chip:

```
<mat-chip class="custom-chip-size">Chip</mat-chip>
```

and then just style it in your .css/scss file:

```
.custom-chip-size {
  padding: 0 8px;
  min-height: 20px;
  font-size: 12px;
}
```

[image]

Comment: .custom-chip-size {
    padding: 0 8px !important;
    min-height: 20px;
    font-size: 12px;
} Adding !important to padding worked for me.